# R - Create a path data structure with indexing based on dates, with carryover 'Destination' becoming 'Origin'

Tags: r, path, flowchart

I have a data structure problem. Having trouble how to begin. I'm unsure if my keywords make sense in the title.

I've tried the following:
[Creating a Origin-Destination Table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343610/creating-a-origin-destination-table-in-r) is the most help so far. --Doesn't get to the level of indexing I think I need.

[Creating origin-destination matrices with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263023/creating-origin-destination-matrices-with-r) -- simple one step origin destination.

## --------------------

My question: How can I create a Origin--Destination data set and have the 'Origin' and 'Destination' ordered by date.

Here is my data set:

```
Student     Classes       time
John        HomeRoom      8:00
John        Math          9:00
John        English       10:00
John        Physics       11:00
John        Art           1:00
John        Lunch         12:00
Sarah       HomeRoom      8:00
Sarah       English       9:00
Sarah       Art           10:00
Sarah       Physics       12:00
Sarah       Lunch         11:00
```

This is what I want my data set to look like:

```
Student  OriginClass time   DestinationClass  timeDest  ClassFlow
John     HomeRoom    8:00   Math              9:00      1
John     Math        9:00   English           10:00     2
John     English     10:00  Physics           11:00     3
John     Physics     11:00  Lunch             12:00     4
John     Lunch       12:00  Art               1:00      5
John     Art         1:00   Home              2:00      6
Sarah    HomeRoom    8:00   English           9:00      1
Sarah    English     9:00   Art               10:00     2
Sarah    Art         10:00  Lunch             11:00     3
Sarah    Lunch       11:00  Physics           12:00     4
Sarah    Physics     12:00  Home              1:00      5
```

There are two tricks:

1. Wrapping around the 'destination' to become the 'origin'.
2. Adding the final 'destination' as home.

I'd figure my next steps are as follows:

- Index classes by Student based on time as 'ClassIndex'
- Set My 'Origin' as 0+[previous row ClassIndex]  ~ not sure how to do
- Create a loop, max(ClassIndex) + 1 = 'Home'

The point behind all of this is to beable to show a flow chart.

John: Home Room -> Math -> English -> Physics -> Lunch -> Art -> Home

Sarah: Home Room -> English -> Art -> Lunch -> Physics -> Home

Comment: Definitely closer bc `timeDest` is working perfectly. `DestinationClass = lead(Classes, default = "Home"` is giving me an error. Error is `Error: not compatible with requested type` -- I'm thinking it's because `Classes` is a string, what do you think? I could do a lookup table with unique classIDs.

Comment: It is working fine for me though assuming that your 'Classes' is `character` class.  BTW, I am using the devel version of `dplyr`.

Comment: Had `Classes` as a factor -- works great. Thanks @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Student) %>% 
   mutate(DestinationClass = lead(Classes, default = "Home"),
          timeDest = lead(time), 
          ClassFlow = row_number())
```